# Set up PSGML Mode on Emacs 24

Tags: xml, emacs, gml, sgml, major-mode

I am desperately trying to set up the PSGML/XML Mode for Emacs 24. I did everything according this explanation: http://www.lysator.liu.se/~lenst/about_psgml/psgml.html

I did `./configure` `./make` `./make install` after unpacking the latest package of the major mode and moved the entire directory into a subdirectory of my .emacs.d directory which is found by emacs.

I added the following to my .emacs file:

```
    (autoload 'sgml-mode "psgml" "Major mode to edit SGML files." t)
    (autoload 'xml-mode "psgml" "Major mode to edit XML files." t)
```

However when run `M-x xml-mode` nothing changes, when I run `M-x sgml-mode` I get a SGML menu entry but all syntax highlighting/indenting/... is gone. When I run either command from the SGML menu I get an error like:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (invalid-function (\` (null (sgml-state-reqs ((\, s))))))
Eager macro-expansion failure: (invalid-function (\` (defmacro ((\, (intern (format     "sgml-eltype-%s" n)))) (et) (list (quote get) et (quote (quote ((\, n))))))))
Loading `psgml-parse': old-style backquotes detected!
cons: Invalid function: (\` (defmacro ((\, (intern (format "sgml-eltype-%s" n)))) (et)   (list (quote get) et (quote (quote ((\, n)))))))
```

I am using all this on a GML-file, that is well formed.

Could anybody help me or recommend another major mode for XML that supports autoindenting/hiding of elements/etc? Thanks a lot in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I didn't use it in ages, but here, [the Wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PsgmlMode) says that this is a known issue and that someone had fixed it and uploaded the fix elsewhere. Could you try that?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I totally overlooked that on the wiki page although I did visit it at some point. It seems to work now. If you ever happen to be in Karlsruhe, Germany I will buy you a beer ;)

Comment: hehe, who knows, maybe someday ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As  wvxvw commented, fixing the old-style macros will make it work - still my preferred Emacs ml-library BTW. Try this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/psgml/